# Find $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r\partial s}$ for $f(x(r,s),y(r,s))$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Given a function of $x$ and $y$, $f(x,y)$, where $x$ and $y$ are **both** implicitly functions of $r$ **and** $s$, how can I find the second mixed partial derivative $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r\partial s}$ of $f$?

---

Differentiating first by $s$ via basic chain rule gives

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}$$

But next differentiating by $r$ is where I get stuck.  I know $\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}$ and $\frac{\partial r}{\partial s}$ are just constants with respect to $r$, which simplifies things, but I can't figure out how to differentiate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ or $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ with respect to $r$.  How do I continue from here?

Comment: For ease of notation, let $f_{x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. As you have found, $ f_{s} = f_{x}x_{s}+f_{y}y_{s} $. Apply product and chain rule and differentiate with respect to $r$ to get $ f_{rs} = f_{x}x_{rs}+x_{s}f_{xx}x_{r}+x_{s}f_{xy}y_{r}+  f_{y}y_{rs}+y_{s}f_{yy}y_{r}+y_{s}f_{yx}y_{r}$

Comment: note that $f_x(x(r,s),y(r,s))$ and $f_y(x(r,s),y(r,s))$. Also $x_s$ and $y_s$ are not constant w.r.t to $r$

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the rule of product when you derivate again.

Notice that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ keep being functions of $x$ and $y$, so there you have to use chain rule again.

Denoting $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r\partial s}$ as $f_{sr}$,
\begin{equation}
f_{sr} = (f_xx_s)_r + (f_yy_s)_r=
(f_{xx}x_r+f_{xy}y_r)x_{s}+f_xx_{sr}+(f_{yx}x_r+f_{yy}y_r)y_{s}+f_yy_{sr}
\end{equation}

Comment: Do you mean they keep being functions of $r$ and $s$?

Comment: $f_x$ and $f_y$ keep being functions of $x$ and $y$ and those keep being functions of $r$ and $s$